# Github-Flavored-Markdown in Python

Tags: python, github, markdown

Does anyone knows of a working Python GFM implementation?

Currently I'm using a [javascript renderer](http://www.freedomsponsors.org/core/issue/1/allow-formatting-controls-on-comment-boxes).
It works, but an actual Python renderer would be the right tool for the job. (FS is a Django app)

I tried combining [this](http://freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) with [this](http://gregbrown.co.nz/code/githib-flavoured-markdown-python-implementation/). But the results are not so good.

relevant code --> https://github.com/freedomsponsors/www.freedomsponsors.org/blob/master/djangoproject/core/models.py
(see IssueComment.toHTML)

Syntax highlighting is a plus.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

GitHub uses [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) which is really a Ruby binding built by github for [Sundown](https://github.com/vmg/sundown).

There's a binding for Sundown in Python called [Misaka](https://github.com/FSX/misaka). If you want to have something closer to the renderer github uses but in python you might start there.

For code highlighting you can use [Pygments with Misaka](http://misaka.61924.nl/#usage).

Comment: [This](https://github.com/freedomsponsors/www.freedomsponsors.org/issues/4) is how I made it work.

If someone else is planning to use misaka, please beware of [this](https://github.com/FSX/misaka/issues/25#issuecomment-8295218)

Answer (score 9):

[Python-Markdown](http://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/) plus [py-gfm](https://github.com/Zopieux/py-gfm) seems to work well. It has the benefit of being somewhat standardized within the Python ecosystem - several extensions for Python-Markdown are available, then additional packages like [django_markdown](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown) can be built on top of Python-Markdown and benefit from its extensions.

Comment: As the new maintainer of [py-gfm](https://github.com/zopieux/py-gfm), I'll try to add missing features in future  releases.

Answer (score 6):

In case helpful for others, I just wanted the Github fenced code syntax, e.g.

````
```python
def hello():
   print('this should be rendered properly')
```
````

[Python Markdown](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Markdown) actually ships with an extension to do this already called [Fenced Code Blocks](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/extensions/fenced_code_blocks.html) that works well.

You just call it like so:

```
page_content = markdown.markdown(source, extensions=[FencedCodeExtension()])
```

Answer (score 2):

[Grip](https://github.com/joeyespo/grip) is also pretty cool and gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Python has its own Markup language that is fairly similar to Markdown: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know (upvoted). I'd rather use md though.

Answer (score 1):

[Github Flavored Markdown in Python (gist)](https://gist.github.com/457617)