# Display the README.md file content in my website

Tags: javascript, html, django, github, readme

I want to display the content of the README.md file of a GitHub repository on my website. As far as I know, I would need to input the repository information (owner and repository) somewhere, which would then return the raw README.md as text for use on my HTML page.

I'm using Django, if that helps.

Comment: Yes. (1.) @squidee_'s answer shows how to fetch the Markdown source on the client side using GitHub's API, but you could also [fetch using Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#examples). You might find it easier to use the raw link instead of the GitHub's JSON-based API: open the README in GitHub's tree view then click the "Raw" button to get to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/README.md`. [I'm posting comments instead of an answer because the question is closed.]

Comment: (2.) For converting the Markdown to HTML, see [Markdown to HTML in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61666570/render-markdown-to-html-in-django-templates), [GitHub-Flavored Markdown in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11943089/github-flavored-markdown-in-python), [CommonMark](https://github.com/commonmark/commonmark.js) (client side, or server-side with Node.js), or [GitHub's Markdown API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/markdown).

Comment: (3.) If you translate the Markdown to HTML as a string (as opposed to using a Django Markdown filter), you'll need to insert the string into your HTML page. You'll probably want to use [Django's templating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial03/#write-views-that-actually-do-something) with [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-safe) to prevent the translated HTML string from being escaped.

Answer (score 2):

You would use GitHub's API to access the repository files, then display the `README.md` file contents in your HTML with an element that preserves line breaks. The API request will default to the repositories default branch (usually `main`). Here is how you could go about doing that.

```js
function getReadme(user, repo) {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/repos/${user}/${repo}/contents/README.md`) // Fetch the file from GitHub's api
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            const content = atob(data.content); // Convert from base64 to readable text
                  document.getElementById("readme-text").textContent = content; // Apply content to the document
            console.log(content); // Log the content to the console
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error)); // Catch any errors
}

getReadme("facebook", "react");
```

```html
<h1>My README</h1>
<pre id="readme-text"></pre> <!-- "<pre>" preserves line breaks -->
```

Comment: Note that files can also be fetched from GitHub using `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${user}/${repo}/master/README.md`, which is a little easier to use (no JSON/base64). And this answer displays the raw Markdown source rather than formatted HTML.